# How to implement a trait on a function with generic argument

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to achieve the following code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeFoo {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

fn test(req: SomeFoo) -> i32 {
    println!("Value: {:?}", req);
    5
}

fn main() {
    let mut handlers = HandlerMap::new();
    handlers.add("foobar1", &test);

    let payload = r#"
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 43
        }"#;

    let result = handlers.dispatch("foobar1", payload);
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

I tried a few approaches to allow to register a function that can than be later called with the correct argument. The most promising was to create a trait that specified a method `call_with_json()` and then implement it for the type `fn(T)`.

```rust
trait CallHandler {
    fn call_with_json(&self, req: &str) -> i32;
}

impl<T> CallHandler for fn(T) -> i32
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    fn call_with_json(&self, req: &str) -> i32 {
        let req: T = serde_json::from_str(req).expect("bad json");
        (self)(req)
    }
}
```

Here playground link with the full impl.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=566e33aab2e3c6d3a090d3b9831a4358

Rust keeps telling me that the trait `CallHandler` is not implemented for fn item `fn(SomeFoo) -> i32 {test}`

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: The compiler is literally telling you what do do ("try casting using `as`").

Comment: Even though there is an error in what it's suggesting... (there should be parentheses there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, each function has its own "function item type", which will usually be implicitly coerced into a function pointer when needed. The function item type is a zero-sized type; since it uniquely identifies a single function, it doesn't need to store any runtime information. Converting it to a function pointer drops the information about the specific function from the compile-time type in favour of a runtime pointer.

The problem with your code is that Rust won't apply implicit coercions to make a type satisfy a trait bound, since there may be various different coercions to do this. So you need to make the cast to the function pointer type explicit to make the code compile:

```
handlers.add("foobar1", &(test as fn(SomeFoo) -> i32));
```

(Note that you also need to remove the unused generic parameter `R` for `HandlerMap::add()`. Since it's completely unused, the compiler will understandably be unable to infer it.)

It would be generally preferable to have a blanket implementation for any type satisfying the trait bound `Fn(T) -> i32`. However, that's not possible in this case due to the generic parameter `T`, which is impossible to infer from the type implementing `Fn(T) -> i32` in the general case, since a type might implement `Fn(T) -> i32` for multiple types `T`. (Of course that would be very unusual in practice, but all that matters for the compiler is that it's possible.)

Comment: Came to the same solution, and prepared a working playground here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c4d3db8d98b8a90579dc400f9e0588e

Comment: Thank you @sven-marnach - a bit disappointed that this does not work the as I expected but the function item was the hint I need to understand why :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to find a way to this without the `as F(_)` bit, though it requires a closure on the heap.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef64cc2bc094ac4c4d3ba2b45c9d1c23